# Set alpha/transparency of whole canvas in Raphael html5

Tags: html, canvas, svg, raphael, opacity

Using Raphael to draw SVG in html5, is it possible to set the alpha opacity of the whole canvas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do. You can define a global [Paper.set](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.set), add each element to the set, and apply the opacity attribute to the set, or use [Paper.forEach()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.forEach) to apply the opacity to each element at once.

---

### Using a Set

Create something like:

```
globalSet = paper.set();
```

Then as you create an element, add it to the set:

```
el = paper.circle(60, 60, 50);
el2 = paper.circle(90, 60, 50);

globalSet.push(el, el2);
globalSet.attr({opacity: .75});
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TA9vn/2/

---

### Using forEach()

Instead of using a set, use the `forEach()` method for paper.

```
paper.forEach(function (element) {
    element.attr({opacity: .75});
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JCvBT/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can change the opacity of a Raphael element like this:

```
  raphaelElement.attr(opacity,.75);
```

If you're going to draw your svg on a canvas, just set context.globalAlpha and all drawing after that will be at the specified opacity:

```
  context.globalAlpha = 0.75;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that in Raphael?

Comment: I edited my answer to include opacity in both canvas and Raphael drawings.

Comment: Raphael doesn't use html5 canvas, so that part doesn't apply here.

Comment: Yea--my bad, It was late at night, I saw Raphael but my mind focused on canvas.

Comment: So it's not possible to apply opacity to all elements in one call? I already have opacity applied to some, and would want a global opacity that applies a further opacity

Comment: You can fake "global" opacity. Start by creating a Set and pushing all your elements into that Set.  Then, each time you want to change "global" opacity, you can use Set.forEach(function(e){var o=e.attr(opacity); e.attr(opacity,o+myGlobalOpacityIncrement);}